# Passthrough tap from uitableview to superview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which is a read-only, no-scrolling view. It's a subview of a view that manages taps. I'd like to pass through any tapping on the tableView to its superView.

I've seen lots of examples of doing this, but nothing that seems to apply to the tableview.

Any direction would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, where the subview doesn't have to do ANY touch handling, you could just set the userInteractionEnabled property of your subview to NO.